# Can someone redirect me to relevant mathematics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, education, linear-algebra

[image: Image from Chapter 3 of Principle of Quantum Mechanics by P.A.M. Dirac]

[image: Image from Chapter 3 of Principle of Quantum Mechanics by P.A.M. Dirac]

These are two paragraphs from Chapter 3 of Principle of Quantum Mechanics by P.A.M. Dirac. I need to know what the relevant mathematics its referring specifically, I have some idea not proper enough though. So if someone can direct me to relevant mathematics, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: [Linear algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39165/linear-algebra-for-quantum-physics)

Comment: Those are three paragraphs.

Comment: I think the question is off-topic. What kind of answer do you expect?!

Comment: I think what I needed to ask was how can we write basis bras as <1| or something like that..

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in quantum mechanics, the braket notation is used :
[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)

Comment: Usually link only answers (or answers heavily dependant on links) are very strongly discouraged as they suffer from link-rot.

Comment: Notation is not maths.