# Best books for learning quantum mechanics from scratch?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Could you please recommend some books for studying quantum mechanics for beginners. The books should have a lot of images, detailed explanations and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Study Quantum Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38963/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Feynman lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_toc.html) is great for beginners, you'll get all the basic concepts without the heavy math and it is really easy and pleasant to read.

Personally, I studied Quantum Physics with [Le Bellac](https://books.google.es/books?id=hBlZu4M51IMC), it is very complete and is very popular in France.