# Recommendations for beginner - intermediate quantum mechanics books

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have an interest in quantum mechanics rather than classical mechanics , so should I read **Feynman Lectures** with those red cover and is it correct or would you suggest some other book for start . And I like to study by making my own notes and my own thoughts , so pls I know you're not a psychiatrist , but pls suggest.

PS : I am a beginner in quantum world

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38963/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is an interesting juxtaposition: *intermediate* textbook for *beginners*.